# iif (Iserror ()) function still returning #error

Tags: function, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following function that creates a column in my query:

MTD: IIf(IsError(FormatNumber([62xx]![F40])),0,FormatNumber([62xx]![F40]))

This is linked to an Excel file and where people put numbers and text in the same column (F40 in this example).  I need to know if the thing I am looking at is a number or text.  If it's text I want a zero, if it is a number I want the number.  I know that when I use FormatNumber([C107_62xx]![F40]) on a text line I get an error.  I would assume when I get an error, then my iif formula above would convert that to a zero and the world would rejoice.  For some reason I am still getting a #error even with my iif statement.  What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried using the IsNumeric function but I still get #NUM! errors that come through.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IsError` does not do what you think it does.  From the help topic, it *"Returns a Boolean value indicating whether an expression is an error value."*  Not whether the expression *triggers* an error, but whether the expression ***is*** an error value.

Sorry, that explanation was probably not clear enough, but I don't know how to do better.  So I'll just suggest you consider this `IsNumeric()` expression for what you want here.

```sql
IIf(IsNumeric([62xx]![F40]), FormatNumber([62xx]![F40]), 0)
```

Here is that same expression in a query with the output below.

```sql
SELECT
    [62xx].F40,
    IIf(IsNumeric([62xx]![F40]), FormatNumber([62xx]![F40]), 0) AS MTD
FROM [62xx];
```

```
F40    MTD
-----  ----
foo    0
1      1.00
2.345  2.35
bar    0
```

Comment: I don't understand why IsError doesn't do what I think it does, but I did try your suggestion.  IsNumeric isn't being very reliable for some reason.  I don't like pulling data from spreadsheets where peple do crazy stuff.  This seems to work though:
`IIf(IsNumeric(FormatNumber([62xx]![F40])),FormatNumber([62xx]![F40]),0)`

Comment: Sometimes Excel and Access don't play as nice as I want them to.    Thank you @HansUp for your help.

Comment: Yeah, about that first part ... `IsError()` can't be used to *trap* an error, only tell you whether something is an error value.  For example, dividing by zero triggers error #11, "Division by zero".  But `IsError(1/0)` will not say True; instead it triggers error #11.  And `IsError(11)` says False.  An actual error value is a different type of critter.  And `IsError(CVErr(11))` does return True.

Comment: So @HansUp how do you get Acces to tell you if something is an Error?

Comment: @JonathanElkins Best I can offer is to set up error handling with `On Error GoTo ...` and then check `Err.Number` and `Err.Description`