# #Func! Error on iif query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Below is my sql query:

```
IIf(remedy_src.Position Is Null,(mid(remedy_src.User,instr(1,remedy_src.User,"(")+1,instr(1,remedy_src.User,")")-2-instr(1,remedy_src.User,"(")+1)),remedy_src.Position) AS [Adjusted User]
```

The point is to extract string from a field. Here's an example of the value:

```
n123456 (name lastname)
```

the `IIf` function returns what is in the brackets:

```
name lastname
```

But. Sometimes the source value looks like that:

```
n123456
```

No brackets, and the `IIf` returns the ugly `#Func!` error which prevents the query to be refreshed in my excel file (external data connection to access db).

I would like to handle this error somehow. Preferably to make the `IIf` function return raw source value if error is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got a solution for this issue, kind of completely reqwriting the code to exclude any finction to return errors.

```
 IIf(remedy_src.Position Is Null,replace(replace(right(remedy_src.User,len(remedy_src.User)-instr(1,remedy_src.User,' ')),'(',''),')',''),remedy_src.Position) AS [Adjusted User]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to catch the error:

```
IIF(IsERROR(IIf(remedy_src.Position Is Null,(mid(remedy_src.User,instr(1,remedy_src.User,"(")+1,instr(1,remedy_src.User,")")-2-instr(1,remedy_src.User,"(")+1)),remedy_src.Position)),
remedy_src.user,
IIf(remedy_src.Position Is Null,(mid(remedy_src.User,instr(1,remedy_src.User,"(")+1,instr(1,remedy_src.User,")")-2-instr(1,remedy_src.User,"(")+1)),remedy_src.Position)) 
AS [Adjusted User]
```

or

```
IIF(InStr("(",remedy_src.user)=0,
remedy_src.user,
IIF(IsERROR(IIf(remedy_src.Position Is Null,(mid(remedy_src.User,instr(1,remedy_src.User,"(")+1,instr(1,remedy_src.User,")")-2-instr(1,remedy_src.User,"(")+1)),remedy_src.Position))
As [Adjusted User]
```

Comment: nope. Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Comment: i think i got over zealous with the copy and paste, copied the "As [Adjusted User]" in a couple places it didn't belong. make sure you remove those and put them where they belong. Either way, the theory is sound, you just need to compensate for my syntax errors..

Comment: yup, i noticed that before :) nevertheless it didn't work

Comment: It seems as though the `IsError` function doesn't quite work in this way.  If you take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670418/iif-iserror-function-still-returning-error) HansUp does a good job explaining it.

Comment: try instr instead to search for your brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this `SQL` string is getting a little too complex to easily work with.  I have made a `VBA` function that should be able to do the same thing but with easily understandable and easier to work with.

**The Code:**

```vb
Public Function ExtractString(str As String) As String

    Dim intFirstBracket As Integer
    Dim intSecondBracket As Integer
    Dim blnValidString As Boolean

    blnValidString = False

    If Nz(str, "") <> "" Then
        intFirstBracket = InStr(1, str, "(", vbTextCompare)
        If intFirstBracket > 0 Then
            intSecondBracket = InStr(1, str, ")", vbTextCompare)

            If intSecondBracket > 0 Then
                str = Mid(str, intFirstBracket + 1, intSecondBracket - (intFirstBracket + 1))
                blnValidString = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

    If blnValidString Then
        ExtractString= str
    Else
        ExtractString= "Default Value" 'Handle this how you want
    End If

End Function
```

So your SQL string would simply be:

```vb
IIf(remedy_src.Position Is Null, ExtractString(remedy_src.User) ,remedy_src.Position) AS [Adjusted User]
```

The function I have tested, the `SQL` I have not so just take that into consideration.

Comment: Well, thanks for that. But the problem with VBA in Access is that you can't export queries that contain VBA functions to Excel.